# Deadlock when worker thread and UI thread calls the same method including invoke ui control

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Here is my code depicts issue:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly  object lockObject = new object();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnWorkerThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeLongRunningThread());
    }

    private void SomeLongRunningThread()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            if (txtResult.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                txtResult.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { txtResult.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); });
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                txtResult.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            }
        }

    }

    private void btnUIThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeLongRunningThread();
    }
}
```

When worker thread started and then  btnUIThread clicked deadlock occurs:

It seems that deadlock occurs on txtResult.InvokeRequried:

- Worker thread pass control to ui thread
- As ui thread has the turn, it both updates txtResult and try to start btnUIThread click.
- Deadlock occurs on line `txtResult.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { txtResult.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); });`

Correct me if I am wrong.

The question is how to handle deadlock?

**Edit**: After valuable answers from fellows, my real projects is more complicated as expected, and lock block has more codes that I should guarantee executed by one thread at a time.

Comment: Is that a verified example, so does it happen with just that code?

Comment: Yes it is @RandRandom

Comment: Separate logics, read required data from UI controls on UI thread, pass it to worker thread, which return after work is complete return calculated data, update UI controls with returned data

Comment: Is that a copy and paste error? ``txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();``

Comment: @RandRandom corrected. Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using `async/await`? Or the Progress<T> class? Which .NET version are you targeting? You don't need `Invoke` in any version since 4.5. And the earliest supported version is 4.5.2

Comment: Agree with @PanagiotisKanavos. If it's a new project than you should use modern TPL, instead of those ancient Invoking

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Nice info, but my version .NET 4

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak are you sure? Very sure? 4.5 is a binary replacement for the unsupported 4. This means that a) your development machine already runs 4.5.2 at least and b) your customer's machine probably does as well, deployed either through Windows Update or any other installed application that requires a supported .NET version

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak another thing to consider. TLS 1.2 was added in 4.5. Without it you probably *can't* access services that require it like Gmail, banking sites, service providers. SSL 3 is already abandoned and service providers often require TLS1.2 *at least*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid a deadlock you should `lock` differently. There's no point in locking all that threading code.
Moreover this lock (lockobject) is not necessary because in your sample `SomeAction()` is already synchronized to execute in the main/UI thread.

```
private void SomeLongRunningThread()
{

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    if (txtResult.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        txtResult.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { SomeAction });
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        SomeAction();
    }


}

private void SomeAction(){
    // This lock is not needed as long this method is only called from SomeLongRunningThread()
    //lock (lockObject)
    //{
        txtResult.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    //}
}
```

Comment: It seems it helps

Comment: If ``SomeAction();`` is already synchronized to execute in the main/UI thread, as you say, why do I need to wrap the code from ``SomeAction();`` into a lock? As I understand it only 1 thread (the main-thread) will execute ``SomeAction();`` at a time, so what is there to lock?

Comment: Now [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784536/deadlock-when-worker-thread-and-ui-thread-calls-the-same-method-including-invoke#comment80515534_46784536) makes more sens

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Yeah, I edited the answer like 10 minutes ago, saying just this. I'll remove that lock from my answer completely to avoid confusion.

Comment: The comment `// This lock is not needed as long this method is only called from SomeLongRunningThread()` is not strictly true. It's only ever called on the UI thread so it doesn't need a lock.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to `lock` here at all.

Calling `txtResult.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { txtResult.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); });` pushes the delegate on to the UI message loop queue. When the loop is ready it pops the delegate and executes. The UI can only run one thing at once - No race and no deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4.5 introduced the [IProgress< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to report progress from threads and tasks, and the [Progress< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation which runs a callback or raises an event in the thread that created it. With this, and `async/await`, you don't need to call `BeginInvoke` or `Invoke.

This code can be simplified by using `Progress` :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
    IProgress<string> _progress;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _progress = new Progress<string>(UpdateUI);
    }

    void UpdateUI(string message)
    {
        txtResult.Text = message;
    }

    private void btnWorkerThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() => SomeLongRunningThread());
    }

    private void SomeLongRunningThread()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        _progress.Report(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
    }

    private void btnUIThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeLongRunningThread();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be related to the issue at all.

Comment: @KostyaK on the contrary, it removes it altogether. There's no need to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` or any kind of locking in current .NET versions.